# Flutter CIrcle Avatar With Border

Tags: flutter

I am trying to create circle avatar with border in Flutter using `CircleAvatar` widget like:

```
CircleAvatar(
    radius: 30,
    backgroundImage: NetworkImage(url),
  ),
```

How can I add border to the result of this code?

Comment: Did you tried wrapping it with Container ?

Comment: I haven't. Will try wrapping inside container.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Wrap `CircleAvatar` widget within another `CircleAvatar` widget and then set different radius and backgroundColor to achieve the required border.

**Here is the code snippet**

```
CircleAvatar(
    radius: 30,
    backgroundColor: Colors.teal,
    child: CircleAvatar(
      backgroundImage: AssetImage(url),
      radius: 28,
    ),
  ),
```

[Code Snippet Link](https://www.codesansar.com/flutter/circle-avatar-border.htm)

Comment: Worked perfectly :)

Answer (score 1):

Like indicated in comments a quite flexible way is to wrap it inside a Container:

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        shape: BoxShape.circle,
        border: Border.all(color: Colors.white),
      ),
      child: CircleAvatar(
        // your avatar properties here
      ),
    );
  }
```

So you can quite freely define how your border should look like
e.g. use "strokeAlign"-Property of the Border.all-Method to define whether the border should use the space inside the CircleAvatar or outside of it.

Answer (score 0):

**only use colors**

```
CircleAvatar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.red,
        radius: 70.0,
        child: CircleAvatar(
          backgroundColor: Colors.orange,
          radius: 60,
        ),
      ),
```

when use from local storage

```
CircleAvatar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        radius: 70,
        child: CircleAvatar(
          backgroundImage: AssetImage("image/bg.jpg"),
          radius: 60,
        ),
      ),
```

if use image from network

```
      CircleAvatar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        radius: 70,
        child: CircleAvatar(
          backgroundImage: NetworkImage(url),
          radius: 60,
        ),
      ),
```

Answer (score -1):

Check [this](https://medium.com/@mohammedijas/circle-image-avatar-with-border-in-flutter-513cdf82df43) link. you will get the code snippet if not here is the code bellow.

the code is;

```
CircleAvatar(
              radius: 55,
              backgroundColor: Colors.teal,
              child: CircleAvatar(
                radius: 50,
                backgroundImage: NetworkImage('url'),
              ),
            )
```